# How can I add oversold and overbought to a Label text change within a pine script code?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I'm trying to enter oversold and overbought to change the label text. the code that I would like to modify with your help is a code that prints the labels with highest high, lower high, high low and lower low in the graph.

updated code:

```
//@version=5
indicator("HH LL", overlay = true, max_labels_count = 500)

length = input.int(defval=50, minval=1, maxval=100, step=1, title='Length')
overSold = input(defval=35, title='oversold')
overBought = input(defval=65, title='overbought')
show_hhll = input.bool(defval = true, title = "Show HHLL")
bgCol = input.color(defval=color.new(#0092e6, 0), title = "Generic BG Color")
upCol = input.color(defval=color.new(color.lime, 0), title = "Up Color")
dnCol = input.color(defval=color.new(color.red, 0), title = "Down Color")
txtCol = input.color(defval=color.new(color.white, 0), title = "Text Color")
txtUPCol = input.color(defval=color.new(color.white, 0), title = "Text UP Color")
txtDNCol = input.color(defval=color.new(color.white, 0), title = "Text Down Color")

price = close
vrsi = ta.rsi(price, length)


float ph = ta.highestbars(high, length) == 0 ? high : na
float pl = ta.lowestbars(low, length) == 0 ? low : na

var dir = 0
dir := ph and na(pl) ? 1 : pl and na(ph) ? -1 : dir

var max_array_size = 10
var zigzag = array.new_float(0)
oldzigzag = array.copy(zigzag)

add_to_zigzag(pointer, value, bindex)=>
    array.unshift(pointer, bindex)
    array.unshift(pointer, value)
    if array.size(pointer) > max_array_size
        array.pop(pointer)
        array.pop(pointer)
    
update_zigzag(pointer, value, bindex, dir)=>
    if array.size(pointer) == 0
        add_to_zigzag(pointer, value, bindex)
    else
        if (dir == 1 and value > array.get(pointer, 0)) or (dir == -1 and value < array.get(pointer, 0))
            array.set(pointer, 0, value)
            array.set(pointer, 1, bindex)
        0.

dirChanged = ta.change(dir)
if ph or pl
    if dirChanged 
        add_to_zigzag(zigzag, dir == 1 ? ph : pl, bar_index)
    else
        update_zigzag(zigzag, dir == 1 ? ph : pl, bar_index, dir)

if array.size(zigzag) >= 6
    var label zzLabel = na
    if array.get(zigzag, 0) != array.get(oldzigzag, 0) or array.get(zigzag, 1) != array.get(oldzigzag, 1)
        if array.get(zigzag, 2) == array.get(oldzigzag, 2) and array.get(zigzag, 3) == array.get(oldzigzag, 3)
            label.delete(zzLabel)
        if show_hhll == true
            hhllTxt = dir == 1 ? array.get(zigzag, 0) > array.get(zigzag, 4) ? "HH" : "LH" : array.get(zigzag, 0) < array.get(zigzag, 4) ? "LL" : "HL"
            labelCol = dir == 1 ? array.get(zigzag, 0) > array.get(zigzag, 4) ? upCol : dnCol : array.get(zigzag, 0) < array.get(zigzag, 4) ? dnCol : upCol
            OS_OB_Col = vrsi <= overSold ? dnCol : vrsi >= overBought ? upCol : bgCol
            OS_OB_Txt = vrsi <= overSold ? txtDNCol : vrsi >= overBought ? txtUPCol : txtCol
            if dir == 1
                cntrl = hhllTxt == "HH" ? "HH" : "LH"
                if cntrl == "HH"
                    zzLabel := label.new(
                         x = math.round(array.get(zigzag, 1)),
                         y = array.get(zigzag, 0),
                         text = "HH",
                         color = OS_OB_Col,
                         textcolor = OS_OB_Txt,
                         style = dir == 1 ? label.style_label_down : label.style_label_up)
                else
                    zzLabel := label.new(
                         x = math.round(array.get(zigzag, 1)),
                         y = array.get(zigzag, 0),
                         text = "LH",
                         color = OS_OB_Col,
                         textcolor = OS_OB_Txt,
                         style = dir == 1 ? label.style_label_down : label.style_label_up)
            
            else
                cntrl = hhllTxt == "LL" ? "LL" : "HL"
                if cntrl == "LL"
                    zzLabel := label.new(
                      x = math.round(array.get(zigzag, 1)),
                      y = array.get(zigzag, 0),
                      text = "LL",
                      color = OS_OB_Col,
                      textcolor = OS_OB_Txt,
                      style = dir == 1 ? label.style_label_down : label.style_label_up)
                else
                    zzLabel := label.new(
                      x = math.round(array.get(zigzag, 1)),
                      y = array.get(zigzag, 0),
                      text = "HL",
                      color = OS_OB_Col,
                      textcolor = OS_OB_Txt,
                      style = dir == 1 ? label.style_label_down : label.style_label_up)
```

first I tried to retrieve the label text using the hhllTxt variable and failed. in the various attempts it printed very few for me or it skipped. I was unable to create four distinct labels.
As for oversold and overbought, I don't know what to do.
For example, I would like the value equal to or less than oversold to change the label name to low. the intermediate value in ll and the one closest to 50% in hl.
I kindly ask for help.

Comment: After many tries, I managed to do something. I would like to reply like the second screen. I'm trying to get a result like in the second screen. thank you so much
[screen with my code in the graph](https://i.imgur.com/SrdfTQq.png)
[result I would like to achieve](https://i.imgur.com/fk0aBuN.png)